# How to give "build run" Permission on a specific job to a user in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

We have a created a Job in jenkins.

How can i give run permission to a user for this specific build Job.

I have referred some Jenkins sites but not got a clear understanding.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Job DSL Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin), then the easiest way you could specify per job permission would be to utilize `Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy` (`Manage Jenkins / Configure Global Security`) and DSL script like the one below:

```
// adds the build permission for the special anonymous user
job('example-2') {
    authorization {
        permission('hudson.model.Item.Build', 'anonymous')
    }
}
```

Additionally, by setting `Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy` you will be able to change project's permission manually, straight from job's configuration page.